# Is it the good way to use Margin/Padding in Xamarin Forms XAML? Or increase the transparent surface of image not using margin and padding?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is it good to use margin/padding to align the position of CachedImage in XAML Xamarin Forms? Or any other preferable/good way to align it so that it can stay consistant to all devices screens?

Like for example:

[image: Image with increased transparent area.]

Comment: I'd use a grid and horizontal/vertical alignment to position an image.

Comment: Basically @SteveChadbourne you don't use Margin/Padding to align your image? Do you mean the HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions?

Comment: Correct. Margin and Padding can be used for small adjustments. HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions can be used to position the image inside the grid cell.

Comment: Great. Thank you @SteveChadbourne for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options, which to use will depend on the rest of your layout. Anyway, increasing the transparent area of the image will not port very well, because of different screen-sizes and -ratios.

Learn about layouts in Xamarin.Forms, it will help you much. On way to center (or otherways align) an image would be to use an `AbsoluteLayout` (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/))

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <Image Source="whatever.png" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,.5,-1,-1"` sets the position of the `Image` to centered, while the size is retained.